# Proof : prime $p$ has the form $4n+1$ or $4n+3$

Tags: number-theory

I am looking at the theorem:

Let prime $p>2$.

$-1$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod {4}$

$-1$ is a non quadratic residue $\mod p$ if and only if $p \equiv 3 \pmod {4}$

If $p=4n+1 : \left ( \frac{-1}{p} \right )=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=(-1)^{2n}=1$

If $p=4n+3 : \left ( \frac{-1}{p} \right )=(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=(-1)^{2n+1}=-1$

But...,when $-1$ is a quadratic residue,how can I show that $p=4n+1$,and when $-1$ is a non-quadratic residue, how can I show that $p=4n+3$ ?

Comment: Firstly, you may want to try to prove by showing that it cannot be 2 or 4 $(mod4)$. Secondly, what do you want us to do with the arrow?

Comment: I mean that at the one case,when $-1$ is a quadratic residue,how can I show that $p=4n+1$,and when $-1$ is a non-quadratic residue, how can I show that $p=4n+3$ ?

Comment: but you asked about the arrow.

Comment: ok. That's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the formula you gave, $1$ is a quadratic residue if and only if $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=1$. This is equivalent to the fact that $(p-1)/2$ is an even integer, i.e.,
$(p-1)/2=2n$. Hence $p=4n+1$. Similarly, $1$ is a quadratic non-residue if and only if $(-1)^{(p-1)/2}=-1$, i.e., iff $(p-1)/2=2n+1$, i.e., iff $p=4n+3$.

Comment: Nice,Dietrich.. I understand... Thank you very much!!!

Comment: @evinda: you are welcome, Evinda.

Answer (score 1):

$-1$ is a quadratic residue iff there exists $x$ such that
$$
x^2\equiv -1\mod p\iff x^4\equiv 1\mod p
$$
iff order of $x$ in modulo $p$ is $4$. On the other hands, using FLT we have $x^{p-1}\equiv 1\mod p$ which implies $4|p-1$. So, $-1$ is a quadratic residue iff $4|p-1\iff p\equiv1\mod4.$