# $\mathbb{F}_p({\rm i}) = \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ iff $p=3\mod 4$

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

I know the fact that
\begin{equation*}
\mathbb{F}_{p^2} = \mathbb{F}_p({\rm i}) \simeq \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+1)
\end{equation*}
for a unit ${\rm i}$, i.e. ${\rm i}^2=-1$, iff $p=3\ {\rm mod}\ 4$ for a prime p, but I can't show or find its proof.

Can anyone show this or tell me a good URL ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think we have covered this here. Did you search the site?

Comment: Perhaps it would be better here not to employ the symbol $i$, which is used for a root of $x^{2} + 1$ in the complex numbers.

Comment: See [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2128421/irreducibilty-of-x21-over-mathbbf-p-with-p-equiv-3-mod-4) for irreducibility, which implies the result.

Comment: The theme has also been broached [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187066/11619) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/795779/11619).

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I did search the site but with some different words so I couldn't find them. I'm really sorry for that.

Comment: No harm done! Searching here takes a bit of experience. Learning [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cleft(%5Cfrac%7B-1%7D%7Bp%7D%5Cright)%24%2C%20%24F_p%5Cleft(i%5Cright)%24%2C%20%24p%5Cequiv3%5Cpmod%7B4%7D%24&p=1) helps when searching, but does not guarantee the best match. I still think that there are older threads about this, but the answers in the linked threads do seem to contain the essentials.